# How can I position a view relative to the screen (i.e. not the parent ViewGroup)?

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewgroup

I want to position a `FrameLayout` in the center of the screen, regardless of the height and position of the parent. So for instance, if I have a parent view that moves around the screen, I don't want my `FrameLayout` to move with it and instead always be centered on the screen.

How can I do this in Android?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a RelativeLayout as a root, then use your FrameLayout. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

 <FrameLayout
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <OtherView/>
    <OtherView>
 </FrameLayout>
 <OtherView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Daniel. Unfortunately this solution does not meet what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to position a view relative to the screen. Similar to `position:fixed` property in HTML.

Comment: oh and why dont use an AlertDialogCustom for inflate your view in the middle? but if you dont want block the user interface with this, can use a Fragment in the middle. Think about it and tell me if you need help.

Comment: That's a good idea but the issue with this is that when I let's say make the parent smaller, the dialog will still be completely visible. So I need the view to be fixed on the screen, however, it still needs to respect the boundaries of the parent `ViewGroup`